# magento installation problems

Tags: magento

hello guys plz can anyone help me with this problem im having from a long tym in the installation of the magento. in the final steps of the installation it is giving the error msg as "the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete" iam not able to find out where excatly is the issue where should i make changes can anyone plz help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have never run into this problem, but with a quick google search, I found this forum post on Magento's website that seemed to provide a solution (at least for the guy who posted it).  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1569/

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember having this problem with some URL I was installing on.  Try checking the "Disable URL Checking", or something (I can't quite remember what the option is called), during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experience of installing magento.

1. Operating System: Only Windows 7 (Long journey with Windows8, Vista)
2. Used Mozilla Firefox, find issues with Chrome.
3. Needed to use Opera browser to upload product images.
4. After applying extensions make sure to delete maintenance.log file

I hope this helps.